# Using Angular how to dynamically bind data from a service to atribute and iterate over it in the template?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a container:

```
<div
    class="example-container flex flex-col text-center h-fit min-h-[20rem] w-[15%] border-2 border-gray-100 rounded-md shadow-md"
  >
    <h2
      class="text-xl font-semibold mx-auto py-4 bg-green-200 w-full drop-shadow-lg"
    >
      Monday
    </h2>

    <div
      #mondayList="cdkDropList"
      cdkDropList
      [cdkDropListData]="Monday"
      class="example-list min-h-[5rem]"
      (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
    >
      @for (item of Monday; track item) {

      <app-drag-drop-item [title]="item" cdkDrag></app-drag-drop-item>
      }
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex"></div>
```

but instead of   `[cdkDropListData]="Monday"` and @for (item of Monday; track item)  that are getting the data from hard coded lists, i want to get the data from service.
I have a working function

```
getTasksForTheDay(day: string) {
    return this.tasks
      .filter((task) => task.day === day)
      .map((task) => task.task);
  }
```

and calling it like getTasksForTheDay('Moday') returns 'Walk', so it works.
I want it to dynamic and i dont want to repeat the code.

`[cdkDropListData]="getTasksForTheDay('Monday')"` and
`@for (item of getTasksForTheDay('Monday'; track item)`
doesnt work.